# Why does this regex not capture anything?

Tags: c#, regex

i know, that i should utilize htmlAgilityPack - but in my case, i do not have any chance for that ... sad but true ...
we have following regex: `<a(.+?)(href=["|'](.+?)["|'])(.+?)>(.+?)</a>`
and following sample input:

```
<A href="
http://dummy.domain/dummy.html
" target="_blank"><b><font face="Arial" color="#0000FF" size="2">
Dummy text
</font></b></a>
```

if i remove the line-breaks inside the groups, everything works fine. i'm running on this on .net c# with `ignore-case`-option.

does `.` not capture any `\r\n`-things?

Comment: [`DOTALL MODE`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654006/how-to-completely-ignore-linebreak-and-tab-in-regex/4655264#4655264)

Comment: @John: you should make that an answer (for accepting), or join me on my `close` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you placed the pipe symbol to signify "OR" in the character class--if that is the case, remove the pipes, the `[]` implies an "OR" of any of its members.

Also, remember that there's the possibility of `\n` anywhere within the HTML, and "." won't catch those characters (it will catch `\r`).

To match newlines, you'll need to either use the SingleLine option, or change the `.` to an alternative such as `[.\n]` or `[\s\S]` in place of the plain `.`. Here's an example with the singleline mode specified inline:

```
(?s)<a(.+?)(href=["'](.+?)["'])([^>]*)>(.+?)</a>
```

Note also the `[^>]*` used here, it's a little simpler than using the non-greedy match.

Comment: well, actually it does ... the regex is correct, but i have to use the `singleline`-option to catch `\n`...

Comment: Right you are! My bad. Edited to include details on whitespace and "."

Answer (score 1):

If you just trying to select everything in between the tags try this

```
<a\b[^>]*>([\s\S.]*?)</a>
```

Comment: actually, i'm not doing a dumb-select here :) ... the groups need to remain as they are. sry ...

Comment: one thing to notice: the execution time of `[\s\S]` is really bad, compared to `.` :)

Comment: it is ugly, \S = selects everything but white space \s = white space, misses from memory, so probably not the best choice, but it does grab everything :)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the . matches any character except a newline.

Comment: actually, i guessed so ... if you add a solution, i would like to tick your answer as correct!