# Make comment code can be written in multiple lines

Tags: c#, syntax, colors, richtextbox

My Code:

```
string comments = @"(\<\!\-\-.+?\-\-\>)";   
MatchCollection commentMatches = Regex.Matches(rtb1.Text, comments); 

foreach (Match m in commentMatches)
{
   rtb1.SelectionStart = m.Index;
   rtb1.SelectionLength = m.Length;
   rtb1.SelectionColor = Color.Green;
}
```

I'm working on a HTML Editor for my school project. My problem here is, the comment part cannot be written in multiple lines. Whenever I make a new line, the whole comment code will turns to black in color. I you guys understand about my problem.

Comment: `.` in regular expressions means _any character except new line_, so multiple lines won't match your pattern.

Comment: This answner can solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654006/how-to-completely-ignore-linebreak-and-tab-in-regex

Comment: And this is a tiny example I made: http://www.dotnetfiddle.net/s9wm5j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RegexOptions.Singleline while matching the pattern as follows:

```
            MatchCollection commentMatches = Regex.Matches(regxTextBox.Text, comments,RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

It will treat the whole string as a single line and will resolve your problem.

Regards,

Nitin Joshi