# Compare strings in C# from different OSs with different escape characters

Tags: c#, string, compare

I am trying to compare to strings in C#. So far so good. The challenge is that these strings have different escape characters as they are from different systems. String "b" is displayed in a Windows Forms element whereas string "a" is read from a webapplication. The "equals"-method tells the strings are different. 
But as the strings are the same but the new line, I wonder if there is a possibility to compare these strings no matter how new lines are encoded.

```
string a = "My cool string\r\nwith two lines";
string b = "My cool string\nwith two lines";

if (a.Equals(b)){
    Debug.WriteLine("Strings match");
}else{
    Debug.WriteLine("Strings do not match");
}
```

Can you help me with the comparison?

Comment: What you could do is, first replace all "\n" and "\r\n" with an empty string and then compare the strings

Comment: I don't know what it would be but I'd imagine that there's a regular expression that could compare two `Strings` while ignoring specific character sequences.

Comment: It looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654006/how-to-completely-ignore-linebreak-and-tab-in-regex) might cover it.

Comment: Hmmm, that might not be as useful as I thought

Comment: it used to be unix was \n, mac was \r, windows was \r\n ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't out of the box, but this extension method will do:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool EqualsIgnoringLinefeed(this string s1, string s2)
    {
        if (s1 == null && s2 == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (s1 == null || s2 == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (s1.Equals(s2))
        {
            return true;
        }

        s1 = s1.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Replace("\r", "\n");
        s2 = s2.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Replace("\r", "\n");

        return s1.Equals(s2);
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
if (a.EqualsIgnoringLinefeed(b))
```

Comment: Great, but I would add a `StringComparison` parameter to the extension method, to cover ordinal/invariant culture/case options.