# How to not match a string instance with a line break?

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to using Regex and was struggling with a problem. I have got to a certain point and I am stuck, I can't figure out how to 'ignore' or not match a pin which has a line break in it which is causing the code to fail the test.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Pin
{
  public static bool ValidatePin(string pin){
     string pattern = "^([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{6})$";
     Regex reg = new Regex(pattern); 
     Match match = reg.Match(pin);
    
     if (match.Success) {
        return true;
     } else {
        return false;
}
```

I have the regular expression above, how would I implement it so that when it tries to match a pin with the line break it returns "FALSE". The failed test pin was:
"1234\n".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to completely ignore linebreak and tab in RegEx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654006/how-to-completely-ignore-linebreak-and-tab-in-regex)

Comment: @LorenzoZane: while I'm pretty sure this question is a duplicate, your proposed one looks like the exact opposite of what this question is asking. The regex is already ignoring the linebreak and returning a match in spite of its presence; the OP wants it to _not_ do that.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4123738) in the duplicate. It addresses the general case and your scenario directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `$` (it can match before the line feed symbol at the string end position) with `\z`, the very end of string, use

```cs
string pattern = @"\A([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{6})\z";
```

`\A` is also useful instead of `^` so as to always match the start of string (if that's your intention).

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/fVSlFN/1).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \A                       the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{4}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (4 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{6}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (6 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \z                       the end of the string
```

Comment: @hawks I reckon http://regexstorm.net/tester is a better tool to check .NET regex validity, but constructing regex is more convenient at regex101.

Comment: May be a silly question but I couldn't find a proper answer on google, what is the point of the "@" at the start of the expression?

Comment: @hawks If you use it, you need not escape backslashes.

Comment: Thank you for the help